# How to define method with same name as variable name?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and trying to do some test code.

Following is my code,

```
class Test
    name = "my name"
    def name
        if self.name.nil?
            self.name = "new name"
        end
    end
end

puts Test.new.name
```

when i run `ruby Test.rb` it gives me stack level too deep error

```
Test.rb:4: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Here i know that self.name will call same method again and again...but how can i achieve such type of requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: Local variables have local scope. The variable `name` is a local variable and therefore not visible in the method `name`. Use an instance variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish but the code you wrote is an infinite recursion since the method `name` is trying to call itself. If you want to make change to the `name` variable, try this:

```
class Test
    attr_accessor :name
    def initialize
        @name = "my name"
    end
    def name
        if @name.nil?
            @name = "new name"
        end
        @name
    end
end

p Test.new.name
```